# Final block not properly padded ,bad key is used during decryption in AES ECB in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, padding

Below AES ECB javascript code is giving the output, but while testing it in online tool it gives padding issue "final block not padded properly,bad key is used" .Is there any way to solve this issue in javascript please suggest

```
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Test","HhiiAlLHowRYoU69", {
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });

        console.log("encryptByAES ciphertext: "+encrypted);

   var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted,"HhiiAlLHowRYoU69", {
             mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
             padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });

        console.log("decryptByAES plaintext: "+decrypted);

OUTPUT OF THE ABOVE CODE

encryptByAES ciphertext: U2FsdGVkX1+heFB5M+220TMdq12Q22/zuSNXXMJg4+0=  
decryptByAES plaintext: Test
```

Comment: Which online tool? Does this tool use the same keystore that you use in local environment?

Comment: i used this online tool https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

Comment: Don't use online tools, they are horrible. E.g. your online tools mistakes a printable string with a key. That mistake alone shows that the author doesn't know squat about encryption.

Answer (score 4):

```
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("HhiiAlLHowRYoU69");

 var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg,key, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
 console.log("Encrypted data ="+encrypted);

     var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted,key, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    var decryptedText = decrypted.toString( CryptoJS.enc.Utf8 );
 console.log( "decrypted Text = " + decryptedText );
```

This is the working solution i got to my above posted problem in javascript.

Comment: Wow Works like a charm, I was like so frustrated and finally I made it work thanks to you Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

CryptoJS decides to interpret your "key" as a password if you pass it a string. Then it derives a key from that password - which is quite different from that password.

> For the key, when you pass a string, it's treated as a passphrase and used to derive an actual key and IV. **Or you can pass a WordArray that represents the actual key.** If you pass the actual key, you must also pass the actual IV.

That's also why your ciphertext is so large: it contains an 8 byte salt and the ciphertext. The salt is combined with the password to derive the key. The salt is preceded with a string / magic `Salted__`, try and view your ciphertext in a hex editor, and you'll find that the 8 first bytes are not all that random.

An AES key should consist of fully unpredictable bits / bytes. That means that a printable string **cannot** be a key, because it leaves unprintable characters out by definition. If you want to use a specific test key, define one using hexadecimals and use `Hex.parse` from the CryptoJS library.

ECB is insecure, you should use an authenticated mode like GCM.

Comment: Thank you for guiding,but i got it working by using Utf8.parse

Comment: I don't know what that means but good on you. Beware that insecure cryptographic code (ECB, bad key space) may well run, but is kind of useless.